# Can't send data to firebase, React, ES6, Redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, redux

So something is wrong and I can't figure out, it's the same like some cases previous which are working:

have initalization and action, action creators:

```
...config

firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const firebase_db = firebase.database().ref();
export const POST_DATA = 'POST_DATA';
export function PostData(post) {
    return dispatch => firebase_db.push(post);
```

reducers:

```
export default function(state={}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case POST_DATA:
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
    };
    return state;
```

and form, state:

```
class NewInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                        adress: [], 
                        owner: [], 
                        city: [], 
                        floor: [], 
                        year: [], 
                        description: [],
                        data: []
        };
    }

    onSubmit(values) {
        this.props.PostData(this.state.data);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: [event.target.value]});
        this.state.data = [...this.state.adress, ...this.state.owner, ...this.state.city, ...this.state.floor, ...this.state.year, ...this.state.description]
```

don't have any error and when console log this.state.data there is expected data... Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you assigning to `this.state.data`?

Comment: I want to send data from all input fields in one array, maybe suggestion for that?

Comment: array looks like this `["Adress", "Owner", "City", "1", "1", "Descriptio"]` and thats how it should look, but it won't send anything to firebase... also, always missing last keyboard press so instead description, there is descriptio, anyone know somthing about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem, it was onSubmit problem with redux form, it was wrote in worng way...